# How do I expand div until a certain height, and only after that scroll?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a div that is originally a certain size, say 100px. I want it to be able  to expand to fit contents say  until 250px, and after that scroll.
I've tried using

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis; max-height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll;
```

But it doesn't work, it scrolls as soon as text overflows 100px.

How can I do this using only css?

Comment: show your html too..

Comment: its a span inside many spans, kind of complicated to include

Comment: ok,add code in codepen.

Comment: A native JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet would actually be the best. It's the button with the `<>` icon

Comment: ```text-overflow: ellipsis; min-height: 100px; max-height: 250px !important; overflow-y: auto;```
see if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ajeet Eppakayala's comment this seems to work, expanding the div to 250px height then showing the scrollbar:

```
<style>
div {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size:20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 250px;
  height:auto;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background-color:cyan;
  margin-top:20px;
}
</style>
<p>height:100px;</p>
<div>
  1<br>2<br>3<br>
</div>
<p>height: whatever is required for the text</p>
<div>
  1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5
</div>
<p>height:250px and scrolling</p>
<div>
  1<br>2<br>3<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>12<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>
</div>
```